# Near horizon limit of near-extreamal black brane

Tags: gravity, black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft

It is known that the near horizon limit of a ($d+1$) dimensional extremal  charged black hole (BH) is $AdS_2\times S^{d-1}$. I was looking at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2694) by Faulkner et al. They consider a ($d+1$) dimensional extremal charged BH (rather black brane) which is asymptotically $AdS$. Now for zero temperature I can use their scaling limits (eqn. (20)) to obtain the $AdS_2\times R^{d-1}$.

Can someone tell me how to use the other scaling limit (eqn. (23)) to obtain the small temperature near horizon limit which is $AdS_2BH\times R^{d-1}$?

I understand this is a bit technical (home work type) question. Any hint or may-be-useful references are be much appreciated!